# Using AWS CLI to query file names inside folders?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Our bucket structure goes from MyBucket -> CustomerGUID(folder) -> [actual files]

I'm having a hell of a time trying to use the AWS CLI (on windows) --query option to try and locate a file across all of the customer folders. Can someone look at my --query and see what i'm doing wrong here? Or tell me the proper way to search for a specific file name?

This is an example of how i'm able to list ALL the files in the bucket LastModified by a date. 
I need to limit the output based on filename, and that is where i'm getting stuck. When I look at the individual files in S3, I can see other files have a "Key", is the Key the 'name' of the file?
[See Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1FIZ.png)

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket --recursive --output text --query "Contents[?contains(LastModified) > '2018-12-8']"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `aws s3 ls` command only returns a text list of objects.

If you wish to use `--query`, then use: `aws s3api list-objects`

See: [list-objects — AWS CLI  Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects.html)